# Different Facebook Auth Dialog in Safari?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, facebook-ios-sdk

I found two different FaceBook auth dialog while using two apps one is "Poker by Zynga" and other one is I am developing.

When I use FaceBook login in "Poker by Zynga" then Safari opens this page:

[image]

And when I use my app which is under development now, then Safari opens this page:

[image]

You can see both of these are two different pages. In Poker by Zynga, it says "Logged in as Vicky Gupta - Log Out" where user can choose Log Out to sign in as a different user. While in my app it says "You are logging into this app as Vicky Gupta", in this there is no Log Out button.  The only way to log in as a different user to open FaceBook in Safari and then log out from there.

Does any one know why this difference is occurring ? am i missing something in FaceBook app settings? Or is this a normal behavior because I don't think so?

Note: I am using the latest FaceBook SDK (with graph api).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest iOS Facebook SDK, I think to logout a user you just have to delete the token obtained by the Facebook main object.